# How to pass in a string input into HTML webpage for javascript function for SHA1 hashing algorithm

Tags: javascript, html

Hello could someone help with passing a string properly when taking user input in HTML to javascript function for a cryptographic hash of SHA1. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here, it might be a small mistake. I just have a basic HTML written in asking for user input and when the button is pressed, it has to return the hashed output using the crypto library. I tried to use both "document.write()" and console.log function to see if it displays the output, but sadly it doesn't work. I believe it must be something wrong with the string type I'm passing in and not necessarily with the hashing algorithm I'm calling in the module.

I'm relatively new to HTML and especially javascript, but I'm trying to learn this based on GeeksforGeeks website. See link for the code which I'm trying to attempt. It's example 2 in the page, but it only has the script alone. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-hash-from-string-in-javascript/

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>SHA1 Hash</title>
   <input type="text" id="userInput"=>Enter string you want to hash using SHA1: </input>
   <button onclick="hash_func()">Submit</button>
        <script> 
        function hash_func()
        {
            var userInput = document.getElementByID("userInput").value;
            const crypto = require('crypto'), 
            hash = crypto.getHashes();

            //passing in user input into x variable
            x = userInput

            // 'digest' is the output of hash function containing  
            // only hexadecimal digits
            hashPwd = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(x).digest('hex'); 
            document.write(userInput)
        }
        </script> 
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: There are several issues with your code. In your JS, at x= userInput, you have not ended the line with semi-colon. Same is the case when at the line require('crypto'). You would need to import Javascript library for crypto to use it. Also, I think the code on that website may be wrong; at least not of Javascript as require() is used in Node

Comment: @AbidSulemanAhmed thanks for point out the missing semicolon at x = userInput . I'm not sure about the other place as that line ended with a comma in the geeksforgeeks website too in sample code.

Comment: Like I said, I don't think the website has been very prudent with the details of the tutorial.